# read value of binary two's complement integer in c++

Tags: c++, binary, twos-complement

I have a binary data file.  There is a binary header of a few thousand bytes.  I task is to read bytes 3000 and 3001.  The good news is that it should read one of two values: 1 or 5.  The hard part for me is that the number is stored as a two's complement integer.  I will put in binary mode, but I do not where to go from there.
I see one route since there are only two values but not sure how to go about it.  I believe I need either 1 = 0000 0000  0000 0001 or 5 = 0000 0000  0000 0101, so I only need to look at byte 3001, the thing is I do not really know how to display a value from an individual byte.  I need either the value of byte 3001, or if there is a way to access individual bits, it would be great to just display byte 3001 on the screen as either 0000 0001 or 0000 0101.

Answer (score 0):

For your task " read bytes 3000 and 3001", just use simple [seekg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/)

```
cin.seekg(3);
char c;
cin >> c;
bitset < 8 > s(c);
cout << s;
```

With this code and input "abcdefg" you will get output "d";

But be careful when work with binary data. For example if you realy sure that from 3000 stored int(typical 4 byte) then there is no problem. But if on this place stored for example short, and you read into int, there it will be 100% some type of garbage and very high chance to corrupt next data.

Comment: cin.seekg(0) would have yielded g right, seekg(1) would have yielded f? (with all the other code the same)